# DynamoDB data model

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Looking for help / suggestions on how to model my data requirements so that it fits with dynamoDB. Modeling it in a relational way is no problem, but using a relational database (RDS) is not an option for the moment.

Let me first state, that I am a total beginner in dynamoDB.

The data requirements I am looking at is the following:
I have a list of Objects (ID, NAME, and some extra attributes).
For each of those objects a reservation can be made on a daily basis by a user.
So a reservation would look like (ID, OBJECT_ID, DATE, USER)

This data should be displayed on screen somewhere in calendar like table with the dates (chronologically) as column headers and the objects as row headers.

I am stuck in finding how to model this to dynamoDB that is efficient.
Initially I was thinking about a json structure that looks like this:

```
object: {
   Id:id
   name:name
   dates:[date:user,date2:user,...]
}
```

But that doesn't seem right for dynamoDb for me.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need 2 tables: `Objects` and `Reservations`

**`Objects`**

- Partition Key: `ID`

You may ask for any object by its `ID`.

**`Reservations`**

- Partition Key: `OBJECT_ID`
- Sorting Key: `DATE` (You need it to order the data by date; **I suppose that DATE is unique for each reservation**)
- other fields: `ID`, `USER`

In order to get your "calendar like table" you have to scan the `Objects` to get all the `ID`s, then, for each `ID` do a query (not easy for a beginner) to retrieve all the reservations for the object.

Gook luck

Comment: Thanks, was thinking about splitting it up in different tables, but wasn’t sure it is a good way to go in dynamo. The date is indeed unique for each reservation. I will give it a try and see how far I get.